# android - Call a notification only once after given amount of time

Tags: android, timer, notifications

I am making a simple budget app that tracks money for a given period of time, it could be for a day or a week. After a day or week has passed a notification should pop up with the message that the budget time has ended.

I want to send a notification after given amount of time and only once, let's say after 1 day the notification pops up, and the user is able to reset the budget.

I have tried using Calendar and Timer with no luck.
Is there a way to pop up a notification after a given amount of time and only once?

This is the code I am currently using.

```
public static final int MY_NOTIFICATION = 1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_budget);

    ... // Inner code

    displayNotification();

}



private void displayNotification(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);


    Notification notify = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_alarm)
            .setTicker("Budget has ended!")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle("The Budget App")
            .setContentText("Your budget has expired!")
            .getNotification();

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION, notify);
}
```

Comment: so what's the problem   ?

Comment: How can I pop up a notification after a set amount of time?

Comment: by Calendar and once by saving boolean key at shared preference

Answer (score 0):

To perform a specific task at a specific time irrespective of the fact app is opened or not, you need a alarm kind of mechanism. 
Depending on the Android version either the JobScheduler, GcmNetworkManager or AlarmManager can be used in an Android application.
I would suggest a library by Evernote which takes care of everything.

[A utility library for Android to run jobs delayed in the background. Depending on the Android version either the JobScheduler, GcmNetworkManager or AlarmManager is getting used. You can find out in this blog post or in these slides why you should prefer this library than each separate API. All features from Android Oreo are backward compatible back to Ice Cream Sandwich.](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)